# Search a string

Tags: javascript, indexof

I have a form that user fill with tags like this:

```
<messageCode>Tag Value 1</messageCode>
<messageVersion>Tag Value 2</messageVersion>
```

And would like to know if there is a way in Javascript to search the following strings:

```
String 1 = <messsageCode>
String 2 = Tag Value 1?
```

I should use index of?

Comment: If you are trying to parse XML, then, well, use an XML parser instead of mucking around treating it as a string. See `DOMParser`.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so, please accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on parsing xml with regexps and string functions, then

```
input.match(/<(.*?)>(.*)<\/\1>/)
```

will return an array, whose `[1]` element is the tagname and `[2]` element the content.

Instead, you should use `DOMParser` to reliably parse the input, and use DOM functions to navigate the result.

Comment: Probably not as well as all the web pages about it, such as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser. You create a parser, then call its `parseFromString` method on a string. Then you navigate the result using all the DOM methods you know and love.

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
```

this will only tell you the start position of welcome. Do you want to retrieve the value?

```
var str = "tag attr = tag value";
var n = str.indexOf("=");
var res = str.substring(n,);
```

Comment: Yes I want to retrieve the value.